# Get Request in universal winJS Project

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, win-universal-app, winjs

I have a map and a rest web service, what I want is to desplay markers in the map 
according to the informations from the web service,this is my code:

map.html:

```
<head>
    <!-- USGS URL data source -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/week.js"></script>
    <!-- Google Maps API reference -->
    <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization">
    </script>
    <!-- mapframe references -->
    <link href="/map.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/map.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="mapdisplay"></div>
</body>
```

week.js in which I call the web service:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "URL",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (results, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(results.stringify);
    },
    error: function (error) { alert('ERROR has occurred!'); alert(JSON.stringify(error)) }
});
```

and map.js to put every local in the map:

```
var dataa;
var map;

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapdisplay'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.840041,10.624909),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });
    eqfeed_callback(results);
    addMarkers();
}

eqfeed_callback = function (results) {
    dataa = results;
}


function addMarkers() {

    for (var i = 0; i < dataa.locals.length; i++) {
        //var quake = dataResults[i];
        //var coors = quake.geometry.coordinates;
        var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(dataa.locals[i].local_longi, dataa.locals[i].local_latit);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLong,
            map: map,
            icon: './images/BB_mapIcon.png'
        });

    }

}

function getCircle(magnitude) {
    return {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: .2,
        scale: Math.pow(2, magnitude) / Math.PI,
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeWeight: .5
    };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I get an exception, Unable to get the "length" property of a null reference or undefined 
miss I any thing in my code
how can I correct my code,to get the data from the web service in week.js and display it in map.js 
thanks for help

I work on a universal WinJS project,and this is the json data in which I want to extract the lattitude/langitude values:

```
{
success: 1,
message: "local found",
total: 1,
locals: [
  {
  id_local: "1",
  local_longi: "14.6996",
  local_latit: "588.39",
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue. From the snippets you have posted, it looks like you aren't using the returned data inside the callback function when/where it is available.

Comment: thanks geocodezip for your reply,I have followed this example http://www.creepyed.com/2012/11/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-on-windows-8/

Comment: I tried instead if using a js file that contains json data,to use an ajax call to get data with a web service and display it in the map

Comment: Where are you calling `eqfeed_callback` from?  If that's required before you can call `addMarkers`, you should probably move the call to `addMarkers` from the end of your `initialize` function, to the `eqfeed_callback` function.

Comment: `eqfeed_callback` isn't being called so the `data` is undefined which causes the exception. you'll need to load the json data before `addmarkers` is called. That will depend on how you call it. Other than that it should be okay as long as you followed [how to add markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) in the google maps documentation

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,I have updated my code,and I have called the eqfeed_callback() before the addmarkers() method,but I still get undifined value for both results and dataa :(